# Yahoo finance or google finance will block if i will subscribe all stocks?

Tags: yahoo-finance, google-finance

I want to retrieve all stocks from few exchanges - by retrieve the stocks that inside those exchanges (by taking from http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx).

And then I will quote for all stocks from google or Yahoo.

My question is if I will quote all of them for every 5 seconds or 10 seconds - will they block me?

What is the correct way for getting all stocks and they updated data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

David,

tl;dr - yahoo finace is OK (scraping 2,000 stocks) if you insert pauses in your code

I have some clumsy, but working code (my first attempt at scrapping) that pulls some data from Yahoo Finance. While I don't like the code and I will rewrite it for nasdaq.com in following weeks, I can tell you that I'm not getting blocked.

I have a few years old list of stocks for Russel 2000 so there are around 2,000 tickers I'm slowly going through and pulling some data from balance sheet. I'm using Selenium (see my question history, there is only one to see/get working code), code loads Chromium web browser (Linux) clicks on Balance sheet, scrape some data, clicks quarterly link, scraps more data and then closes the browser. For every ticker (stock).

Just to be on a safe side, I put several pauses into my code, for every scrap or navigation on site I added between 5 and 10 seconds. That way I'm slowly scraping data and Yahoo seems to be OK with this :-) It takes about one minute per ticker. I'm running this scrap job (for the first time!) now for over 30 hours lol and I'm currently at ticker that starts with T so I have few more hours to go.

I have read somewhere that some sites can spot this slow scraping also. So as an idea, instead of just hard code pause of say 7 seconds, you could run random number generator between IDK, 7-15 seconds and that way pauses will be more random and less prone to be spotted... Just a though Hope this helps a little bit even if with delay.

Ah, and if this answer does help you, please be so kind to mark it as solved and up vote it. Maybe I can get a point or two for it. My points are so low I can't even vote other posts that I like and that helped me.